# Calling HSQL function from JDBC

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, hsqldb

I have the following stored procedure function in HSQLDB 2.3.4 straight from the [documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_psm_routines)

```
CREATE FUNCTION an_hour_before (t TIMESTAMP)
   RETURNS TIMESTAMP
   RETURN t - 1 HOUR;
/;
```

I try to call the function with

```
try (Connection connection = this.dataSource.getConnection()) {
    try (CallableStatement call = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call an_hour_before(?)}")) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I get a `NullPointerException` with the following stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hsqldb.StatementProcedure.getParametersMetaData(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.result.Result.newPrepareResponse(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCCallableStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareCall(Unknown Source)
    at com.acme.HsqlTest.test(HsqlTest.java:42)
    ...
```

Comment: Is `this.dataSource.getConnection()` returning `null`?

Comment: @GordThompson no the `NullPointerException` comes from inside the HSQLDB implementation of `#prepareCall`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with HSQLDB 2.3.4 and has been fixed in SVN repository. Use an earlier release version or compile the jar from /base/trunk code.

Comment: indeed downgrading to 2.3.3 fixes the issue. Do you have an ETA on 2.3.5?